# Помогите задать переменную в Postman через вкладку Tests

Tags: javascript, json, api, test-automation, postman

Имеется такой ответ после выполнения запроса

```
"response": {
        "count": 20,
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 5090,
                "from_id": 9999,
                "owner_id": 9999,
                "date": 1598455953,
//Ну и так далее
```

Хочу добавить в переменную среды значение поля id. Пишу следующее:

```
jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("id", jsonData.response.items.id);
```

Но в переменную ничего не сохраняется. Однако, таким же способом я могу сохранить значение поля count.
Помогите, плиз, написать скрипт, что бы сохранить id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас `items` массив, поэтому:

```
pm.environment.set("id", jsonData.response.items[0].id);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Действительно. Как я мог это упустить...

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json().items[0].id;
pm.environment.set('id', jsonData)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]